# Hibernate ManyToOne

Tags: java, hibernate

Пытаюсь получить две сущности, связанные между собой связью многие к одному, использую `hibernate` на аннотациях. Причем хочу связать так, чтобы связь проходила через одно поле, а не ссылкой на объект другого класса.

Я написал вот такой вот код:

```
@Entity(name = "A")
@Table(name = "As")
public class A implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "A_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
}

@Entity(name = "B")
@Table(name = "Bs")
public class B implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "B_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = A.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_id", referencedColumnName = "A_id")
    private long owner;
}
```

Конфигурирование:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
    .addAnnotatedClass(A.class)
    .addAnnotatedClass(B.class)
    .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect")
    .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test")
    .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "name")
    .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "password")
    .setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false")
    .setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
```

Но в итоге в ходе выполнения программы я получаю вот такую вот ошибку:

```
ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  [] : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table Bs drop foreign key FK350jq24kcslxfkdvajsu5yy1o
ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  [] : Table 'test.bs' doesn't exist
```

Как я понимаю, она происходит в момент создания схемы (ну и вторая в момент удаления) и связана, скорее всего с неправильными аннотациями. Собственно вопрос - в чем конкретно может крыться ошибка, из-за которой не объединяются сущности нужной связью? Есть ли еще какие-нибудь способы объединить сущности подобным образом?

---

Как выяснилось, эта ошибка получается при удалении таблицы с констрейтом. 
И как следствие меняется вопрос: в каком порядке hibernate удаляет таблицы при `create-drop`? Как этот порядок изменить/задать явно, чтобы не возникало проблем с констрейтами?

Comment: Вот [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714491/hibernate-and-mysql-with-create-drop-option-console-output-shows-error-but) вроде похожая ситуация.  Не особо сам силен в хибернейте, но как по мне проблемка возможно может решиться заменой значения проперти `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` на create или update  ([для справки](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do))

Comment: @I.Smirnov, действительно, замена на update решает проблему, а вот create продолжает выдавать эту же ошибку. Это странно, потому что ошибка была и при первом запуске, где база была пуста и удаляться ничего не должно было. Тем не менее, для меня требуется именно `create-drop`.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен. А теперь все по порядку:
Ошибка возникала из-за того, что сущность `B` ссылалась на сущность `A`. При удалении, сперва удалялась таблица, связанная с сущностью `A`, а на нее из-за связи стоял constraint.

Hibernate, судя по всему, создает и удаляет таблицы в порядке объявления:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
    .addAnnotatedClass(A.class) //Сперва таблица сущности A
    .addAnnotatedClass(B.class) //Затем таблица сущности B
    //Другие настройки
```

Поэтому при удалении сперва была попытка убить `A`, на которую ссылалась `B`.

Запись в конфигурацию сущностей в правильном порядке решила эту проблему:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
    .addAnnotatedClass(B.class)
    .addAnnotatedClass(A.class)
    //Другие настройки
```

Comment: почему не использовать каскадное удаление?